# Retraining Spacy's Noun Chunks

Tags: python, spacy

I have the following sentences:

```
sent_1 = 'The cat caught the mouse.'
sent_2 = 'The cat caught and killed the mouse.'
```

Now I want to know who did what to whoom. Spacy's noun_chunks work perfectly in the first case, indicating "The cat" as the "nsubj" with the chunk.root.head.text being "caught". Likewise, "the mouse" is correctly classified as being the "dobj" with again "caught" as chunk.root.head.text. So it is easy to match these two.

However, in the second case, the nsubj gets "caught" as its chunk.root.head.text while the dobj gets "killed", whereas they actually would belong together. Is there a way to account for this kind of cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case 'killed' is the head of the 'the mouse' as it is the text connecting the noun chunk to the rest of the phrase. From the spacy documentation:

> Root text: The original text of the word connecting the noun chunk to the rest of the parse.
> https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#noun-chunks

N.b. that link has a very similar example to yours - a sentence with multiple noun chunks with different roots. ('Autonomous cars shift insurance liability toward manufacturers')

To answer your question, if you want 'caught' to be found as the head in both instances, then really what you're asking for is to recursively check the head of the tree for each noun_chunk... something like this:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')   
doc = nlp('The cat caught and killed the mouse.')
[x.root.head.head for x in doc.noun_chunks]
```

which avails:

```
[caught, caught]
```

N.b, this works for your example but if you needed to handle arbitrary sentences then you'd need to do something a bit more sophisticated, i.e. actually recursing the tree. e.g.

```
def get_head(x): 
    return x.head if x.head.head == x.head else get_head(x.head)
```

resulting in:

```
doc2 = nlp("Autonomous cars shift insurance liability toward manufacturers away from everyday users") # adapted from the spacy example with an additional NC 'everyday users' added

In [17]: [get_head(x.root.head) for x in doc.noun_chunks]                                                                                                                               
In [187]: [caught, caught]

In [18]: [get_head(x.root.head) for x in doc2.noun_chunks]                                                                                                                              
Out[18]: [shift, shift, shift, shift]
```